# Improve awk command processing file

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, text

**Situation**

I have awk command reads results from mywebsite.log  current command

```
awk 'BEGIN{ curr_d=strftime("%d/%b/%Y", systime()) }
$3~"^\\["curr_d{ cc[$8]++ } 
END{ for(i in cc) print i":"cc[i] }' /var/log/mywebsite.log > /home/mywebsite/www/countries.txt
```

Is extract only country code and counts country codes then exported to countries.txt as below for same day records only getting the day from linux.

```
IN:35
US:123
QA:3
RU:23
MA:23
```

**Desired Output**:

I would like to get only most visited 20 IP address and count how many times these ip addresses visited same day. The day match with linux date (today) then save to countries2.txt

```
168.235.194.192-US:10
12.34.65.34-RU:5
223.223.129.225-IN:4
34.21.57.1-QA:2
212.252.112.45-MA:2
```

/var/log/mywebsite.log

```
        123.223.129.225 - [25/Nov/2017:02:01:59 +1100] GET /pdf/aloha-micronutrients.html HTTP/1.1 US
        64.223.129.225 - [25/Nov/2017:02:01:59 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        53.223.129.225 - [25/Nov/2017:02:01:59 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 IN
        223.223.129.225 - [26/Nov/2017:02:01:59 +1100] GET /pdf/role-of-micronutrients.html HTTP/1.1 IN
        223.223.129.225 - [26/Nov/2017:02:01:59 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 IN
        223.223.129.225 - [26/Nov/2017:02:01:59 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 IN
        223.223.129.225 - [26/Nov/2017:02:01:59 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 IN
        66.249.92.158 - [26/Nov/2017:02:02:00 +1100] GET /pdf/role-of-micronutrients.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:02:07 +1100] GET /pdf/gastroscopy.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.194.192 - [26/Nov/2017:02:02:08 +1100] GET /pdf/astringents.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.194.192 - [26/Nov/2017:02:02:08 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.194.192 - [26/Nov/2017:02:02:08 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:02:18 +1100] GET /Why-study-literature--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.11 - [26/Nov/2017:02:02:39 +1100] GET /index.php/about/ HTTP/1.1 US
        37.211.15.120 - [26/Nov/2017:02:02:41 +1100] GET /The-Honey-Bee--Florida-State-University--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 QA
        157.55.39.169 - [26/Nov/2017:02:02:47 +1100] GET /pdf/emt-refresher-class.html HTTP/1.1 US
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:02:49 +1100] GET /urea-urei-urease-01-M-urea---pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:11 +1100] GET /pdf/typhoon-presentation.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.194.192 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:13 +1100] GET /pdf/astringents.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.194.192 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:13 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:18 +1100] GET /Trade-Secrets--JurisDiction--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        196.190.64.27 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:18 +1100] GET /pdf/antibiotics-residues.html HTTP/1.1 ET
        168.235.194.192 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:33 +1100] GET /?s=astringents+and+emetics HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.194.192 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:34 +1100] GET /pdf/astringents-and-emetics.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.194.192 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:34 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:37 +1100] GET /pdf/crossing-red-sea.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.11 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:47 +1100] GET /Wilderness-Manager-Survey--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        71.61.49.221 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:47 +1100] GET /pdf/sbar.html HTTP/1.1 US
        71.61.49.221 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:47 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        71.61.49.221 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:47 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 US
        71.61.49.221 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:48 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 US
        196.190.64.27 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:55 +1100] GET //antibiotics-residues-web-Guidelines-for-Antibiotic-Residue-Avoidance--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 ET
        168.235.194.192 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:56 +1100] GET /pdf/astringents.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.194.192 - [26/Nov/2017:02:03:56 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        196.190.64.27 - [26/Nov/2017:02:04:00 +1100] GET /antibiotics-residues-web-Guidelines-for-Antibiotic-Residue-Avoidance--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 ET
        66.249.92.129 - [26/Nov/2017:02:04:03 +1100] GET /antibiotics-residues-web-Guidelines-for-Antibiotic-Residue-Avoidance--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:04:07 +1100] GET /pdf/hose-drill-fire-fighting-training.html HTTP/1.1 US
        209.126.120.38 - [26/Nov/2017:02:04:12 +1100] GET /pdf/sbar.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:04:18 +1100] GET /WAS-THE-ALAMO-A-DEFEAT-OR-A-VICTORY-OR-A-DEFEAT--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        141.8.143.151 - [26/Nov/2017:02:04:18 +1100] GET /Quality-Tools--PCMAC--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.11 - [26/Nov/2017:02:04:37 +1100] GET /pdf/environmental-impacts-of-pesticides-effects.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:04:48 +1100] GET /Fly-Eagle-Fly-PowerPoint-2--Jefferson-County-Schools-TN--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.195.45 - [26/Nov/2017:02:04:59 +1100] GET /pdf/story-boarding.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.195.45 - [26/Nov/2017:02:04:59 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        117.211.126.164 - [26/Nov/2017:02:06:05 +1100] GET /pdf/food-preservation-methods-.html HTTP/1.1 IN
        117.211.126.164 - [26/Nov/2017:02:06:06 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 IN
        117.211.126.164 - [26/Nov/2017:02:06:06 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 IN
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:06:06 +1100] GET /pdf/bearing-materials.html HTTP/1.1 US
        117.211.126.164 - [26/Nov/2017:02:06:14 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 IN
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:06:18 +1100] GET /Programme-6-Water-Resources-Management-Development------pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:06:36 +1100] GET /pdf/endocrine-disruption.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:06:48 +1100] GET /Pre-Algebra--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        196.86.85.113 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:06 +1100] GET /pdf/applied-linguistics.html HTTP/1.1 MA
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:06 +1100] GET /Nurse-to-Patient-Ratio--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        196.86.85.113 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:08 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 MA
        196.86.85.113 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:09 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 MA
        196.86.85.113 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:09 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 MA
        66.249.92.159 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:11 +1100] GET /pdf/applied-linguistics.html HTTP/1.1 US
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:14 +1100] GET /pdf/on-thypoid.html HTTP/1.1 US
        196.86.85.113 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:16 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 MA
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:18 +1100] GET /PowerPoint-Template-GuideStone-Corporate-Presentations--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:38 +1100] GET /pdf/Embracing-Generational-Differences--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        196.86.85.113 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:41 +1100] GET //Applied-Linguistics--Ohio-State-University--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 MA
        196.86.85.113 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:42 +1100] GET /Applied-Linguistics--Ohio-State-University--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 MA
        168.235.195.239 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:42 +1100] GET /pdf/prokinetics-antiemetics.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.195.239 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:42 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        103.231.160.187 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:43 +1100] GET /pdf/electrostatics-gauss-s-law-and-its-applications.html HTTP/1.1 BD
        103.231.160.187 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:44 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 BD
        103.231.160.187 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:44 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 BD
        103.231.160.187 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:44 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 BD
        103.231.160.187 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:44 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 BD
        66.249.92.158 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:45 +1100] GET /pdf/electrostatics-gauss-s-law-and-its-applications.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.11 - [26/Nov/2017:02:07:47 +1100] GET /pdf/roll-of-thunder-hear-my-cry.html HTTP/1.1 US
        103.231.160.187 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:03 +1100] GET //electrostatics-gauss-s-law-and-its-applications-web--Principles-with-Applications-7--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 BD
        103.231.160.187 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:03 +1100] GET /electrostatics-gauss-s-law-and-its-applications-web--Principles-with-Applications-7--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 BD
        103.231.160.187 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:03 +1100] GET /download.jpg HTTP/1.1 BD
        66.249.92.158 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:04 +1100] GET /electrostatics-gauss-s-law-and-its-applications-web--Principles-with-Applications-7--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:06 +1100] GET /pdf/ricci-maternity.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:18 +1100] GET /Pathology--pcmac--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        106.202.142.57 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:23 +1100] GET /pdf/structure-of-atom-for-class-11th.html HTTP/1.1 IN
        106.202.142.57 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:23 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 IN
        106.202.142.57 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:24 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 IN
        106.202.142.57 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:24 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 IN
        66.249.92.159 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:25 +1100] GET /pdf/structure-of-atom-for-class-11th.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.195.239 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:27 +1100] GET /pdf/astringents.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.195.239 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:27 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        75.188.138.63 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:28 +1100] GET /pdf/ethics-in-corrections.html HTTP/1.1 US
        75.188.138.63 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:28 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        75.188.138.63 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:28 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 US
        75.188.138.63 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:28 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 US
        106.202.142.57 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:28 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 IN
        66.249.92.158 - [26/Nov/2017:02:08:29 +1100] GET /pdf/ethics-in-corrections.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:09:17 +1100] GET /Part-III--Modes-of-Reproduction--Arkansas-State-University--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.11 - [26/Nov/2017:02:09:37 +1100] GET /pdf/composites.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.11 - [26/Nov/2017:02:09:47 +1100] GET /COMBINING-ECONOMICS-WITH-NETWORK-ENGINEERING--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:12:47 +1100] GET /pdf/materials-requirements-planning--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:12:48 +1100] GET /pdf/sectional-anatomy-brain.html HTTP/1.1 US
        66.249.66.94 - [26/Nov/2017:02:12:52 +1100] GET /pdf/bat-pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:13:01 +1100] GET /HANDWASHING-Timeless-Wisdom--A-Healthy-Habit--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:13:07 +1100] GET /Common-Diseases-of-Small-Animals--Northwest-ISD--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:13:17 +1100] GET /Nomadic-Empires-and-Eurasian-Integration--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        2.31.250.240 - [26/Nov/2017:02:13:45 +1100] GET /pdf/pink-floyd-power-point.html HTTP/1.1 GB
        2.31.250.240 - [26/Nov/2017:02:13:45 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 GB
        2.31.250.240 - [26/Nov/2017:02:13:45 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 GB
        2.31.250.240 - [26/Nov/2017:02:13:45 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 GB
        2.31.250.240 - [26/Nov/2017:02:13:46 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 GB
        157.55.39.169 - [26/Nov/2017:02:13:48 +1100] GET /pdf/firefighter-safty-and-health.html HTTP/1.1 US
        66.249.92.129 - [26/Nov/2017:02:13:49 +1100] GET /pdf/pink-floyd-power-point.html HTTP/1.1 US
        34.207.174.103 - [26/Nov/2017:02:13:55 +1100] GET /pdf/pink-floyd-power-point.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:14:10 +1100] GET /pdf/fire-team-formations.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:14:11 +1100] GET /pdf/socialization-process.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:14:17 +1100] GET /Erythrocyte-Sedimentation-Rare--port-health-gov-ir--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:14:26 +1100] GET /FAST-Exam--lectures-shanyar-com--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        95.233.1.98 - [26/Nov/2017:02:14:31 +1100] GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1 IT
        95.233.1.98 - [26/Nov/2017:02:14:33 +1100] GET / HTTP/1.1 IT
        71.61.49.221 - [26/Nov/2017:02:14:37 +1100] GET /pdf/sbar.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:14:37 +1100] GET /American-Heart-Association--Skidmore-College--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:14:47 +1100] GET /Truth-in-Justice--stingraybobs-weebly-com--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        66.249.66.65 - [26/Nov/2017:02:14:59 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:15:08 +1100] GET /Animal-VirusHost-Interactions--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:15:17 +1100] GET /pdf/leadership-in-nursing-pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:15:47 +1100] GET /Presentation-title--Teachinglinks-net--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.198.112 - [26/Nov/2017:02:15:49 +1100] GET /pdf/nozzles-pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.198.112 - [26/Nov/2017:02:15:49 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:15:51 +1100] GET /pdf/fatty-acids-beta-oxidation.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:15:54 +1100] GET /pdf/cantilever-beam-analysis.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.198.112 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:02 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:08 +1100] GET /pdf/anesthesia-for-thyroid-surgery.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.198.112 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:10 +1100] GET //nozzles-opwglobal-Why-Are-These-Nozzles-Found--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.198.112 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:11 +1100] GET /nozzles-opwglobal-Why-Are-These-Nozzles-Found--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.198.112 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:11 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:17 +1100] GET /pdf/english-pronunciation-exercises.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:27 +1100] GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.11 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:36 +1100] GET /Orthopaedic-special-tests-for-the-shoulder--Stort-Physio--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.49.7.217 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:39 +1100] GET /pdf/typhoid-vaccine.html HTTP/1.1 IN
        157.49.7.217 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:39 +1100] GET /pdf/typhoid-vaccine.html HTTP/1.1 IN
        157.49.7.217 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:40 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 IN
        157.49.7.217 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:40 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 IN
        157.49.7.217 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:40 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 IN
        51.15.44.92 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:40 +1100] GET /Rocks-and-Minerals--Edgewood-High-School--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 GB
        157.49.7.217 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:42 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 IN
        66.249.92.159 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:43 +1100] GET /pdf/typhoid-vaccine.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:16:47 +1100] GET /PROYECTOS-DE-AHORRO-DE-ENERGIA-ELECTRICA--Luis-Alberto-Arcos------pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.198.112 - [26/Nov/2017:02:17:03 +1100] GET //nozzles-bae-A-Summary-of-Studies-Comparing--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.198.112 - [26/Nov/2017:02:17:04 +1100] GET /nozzles-bae-A-Summary-of-Studies-Comparing--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        168.235.198.112 - [26/Nov/2017:02:17:04 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:17:08 +1100] GET /pdf/test-construction.html HTTP/1.1 US
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:17:16 +1100] GET /The-Japan-Culture--Rice-University--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:17:17 +1100] GET /pdf/brodmans-areas.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:17:47 +1100] GET /Organisational-Buying-Behaviour--McGrawHill-Education--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:06 +1100] GET /pdf/organizational-behaviour-robbins-chapter-2.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:17 +1100] GET /pdf/fluid-management-in-children.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:19 +1100] GET /pdf/sociology-anthropology.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.169 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:37 +1100] GET /pdf/macro-minerals-pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        110.54.187.210 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:39 +1100] GET /pdf/facts-and-opinion-lessons.html HTTP/1.1 PH
        110.54.187.210 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:40 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 PH
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:40 +1100] GET /pdf/plant-nutrition.html HTTP/1.1 US
        110.54.187.210 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:41 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 PH
        110.54.187.210 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:41 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 PH
        110.54.187.210 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:42 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 PH
        66.249.92.159 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:44 +1100] GET /pdf/facts-and-opinion-lessons.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.156 - [26/Nov/2017:02:18:47 +1100] GET /POSTPARTUM-DEPRESSION-BEYOND-THE-BLUES--Utah-Department-of------pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        67.111.46.50 - [26/Nov/2017:02:19:02 +1100] GET /pdf/GLASS-IONOMER-CEMENT--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        67.111.46.50 - [26/Nov/2017:02:19:02 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        67.111.46.50 - [26/Nov/2017:02:19:02 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 US
        67.111.46.50 - [26/Nov/2017:02:19:02 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 US
        67.111.46.50 - [26/Nov/2017:02:19:04 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 US
        66.249.92.158 - [26/Nov/2017:02:19:04 +1100] GET /pdf/GLASS-IONOMER-CEMENT--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        207.46.13.186 - [26/Nov/2017:02:19:07 +1100] GET /pdf/pstn.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.169 - [26/Nov/2017:02:19:17 +1100] GET /pdf/seed-dormancy-and-its-importance-pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:19:43 +1100] GET /pdf/sccm-2012-r2.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.169 - [26/Nov/2017:02:19:47 +1100] GET /pdf/laser-angioplasty.html HTTP/1.1 US
        8.37.232.108 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:01 +1100] GET /pdf/leukocyte-disorders.html HTTP/1.1 US
        8.37.232.108 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:01 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 US
        8.37.232.108 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:01 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        8.37.232.108 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:01 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 US
        8.37.232.108 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:04 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 US
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:07 +1100] GET /artificial-intelligence-2016-cs-AI-or-Computational-Intelligence-There--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        8.37.235.34 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:07 +1100] GET /pdf/basic-electrical-substation.html HTTP/1.1 US
        8.37.235.34 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:07 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        8.37.235.34 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:07 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 US
        8.37.235.34 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:07 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 US
        8.37.235.34 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:09 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.169 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:17 +1100] GET /pdf/operating-brts.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:18 +1100] GET /pdf/mrcp-paces.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.169 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:47 +1100] GET /pdf/1-corinthians.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:20:53 +1100] GET /pdf/electric-shock-causes-symptoms-treatment.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:21:11 +1100] GET /pdf/mk.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.169 - [26/Nov/2017:02:21:17 +1100] GET /pdf/have-got-exercises.html HTTP/1.1 US
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:21:31 +1100] GET /pdf/types-of-cement-pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:21:44 +1100] GET /pdf/postmodernism-theory.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.11 - [26/Nov/2017:02:21:47 +1100] GET /Basic-Traffic-Stops--Career-and-Technical-Education-cteunt--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        207.46.13.186 - [26/Nov/2017:02:22:07 +1100] GET /JET-PROPULSION--sseaimes-files-wordpress-com--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        207.46.13.186 - [26/Nov/2017:02:22:17 +1100] GET /pdf/teton-dam-failure-presentations.html HTTP/1.1 US
        68.180.229.87 - [26/Nov/2017:02:22:26 +1100] GET /tree-falling-smithsgradesix-Trees-and-Forests-%E2%80%93-Falling--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        194.187.171.53 - [26/Nov/2017:02:22:30 +1100] GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 FR
        207.46.13.186 - [26/Nov/2017:02:22:37 +1100] GET /pdf/accounting-and-finance-for-bankers-jaiib.html HTTP/1.1 US
        207.46.13.186 - [26/Nov/2017:02:22:47 +1100] GET /Part-1--Page--Health-Care-Conference-Administrators-Home--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:22:50 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:23:11 +1100] GET /pdf/service-excellence.html HTTP/1.1 US
        207.46.13.186 - [26/Nov/2017:02:23:17 +1100] GET /pdf/beautiful.html HTTP/1.1 US
        207.46.13.186 - [26/Nov/2017:02:23:37 +1100] GET /pdf/usps-retirement.html HTTP/1.1 US
        131.253.25.254 - [26/Nov/2017:02:23:41 +1100] GET /pdf/nursing-and-neuro-assessment.html HTTP/1.1 US
        207.46.13.186 - [26/Nov/2017:02:23:47 +1100] GET /Year-10-Summer-Exams--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        85.195.116.66 - [26/Nov/2017:02:23:57 +1100] GET / HTTP/1.0 DE
        54.82.61.140 - [26/Nov/2017:02:27:23 +1100] GET /pdf/medical-surgical-nursing.html HTTP/1.1 US
        68.180.229.87 - [26/Nov/2017:02:27:24 +1100] GET /fasteners-cengage-Understand-the-theory-behind-torquetoyield--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        67.141.91.182 - [26/Nov/2017:02:27:25 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.169 - [26/Nov/2017:02:27:39 +1100] GET /pdf/management-of-patients-with-neurologic-trauma.html HTTP/1.1 US
        207.46.13.186 - [26/Nov/2017:02:27:47 +1100] GET /Earth-Science-Chapter-12--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:17 +1100] GET /Wrist-and-Hand--groupf2-yolasite-com--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:17 +1100] GET /pdf/seasonality-of-reproduction.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:18 +1100] GET /pdf/cell-phone-infrastructure.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.169 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:37 +1100] GET /pdf/nfpa-20.html HTTP/1.1 US
        89.3.118.149 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:42 +1100] GET /pdf/recombinant-proteins.html HTTP/1.1 FR
        89.3.118.149 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:42 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 FR
        89.3.118.149 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:42 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 FR
        89.3.118.149 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:42 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 FR
        66.249.92.159 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:44 +1100] GET /pdf/recombinant-proteins.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:47 +1100] GET /reakes-weebly-com--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        89.3.118.149 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:48 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 FR
        119.95.172.9 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:49 +1100] GET /pdf/first-vita-plus.html HTTP/1.1 PH
        119.95.172.9 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:50 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 PH
        119.95.172.9 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:50 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 PH
        119.95.172.9 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:50 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 PH
        34.230.8.39 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:53 +1100] GET /pdf/recombinant-proteins.html HTTP/1.1 US
        68.180.229.87 - [26/Nov/2017:02:28:53 +1100] GET /N--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.169 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:07 +1100] GET /pdf/radiation-therapy.html HTTP/1.1 US
        66.249.92.129 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:10 +1100] GET /pdf/first-vita-plus.html HTTP/1.1 US
        89.3.118.149 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:17 +1100] GET /?s=recombinant+proteins HTTP/1.1 FR
        89.3.118.149 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:17 +1100] GET /pdf/recombinant-proteins.html HTTP/1.1 FR
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:17 +1100] GET /OSEP-Update-on-Identification-and-Correction-of-Noncompliance------pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        119.95.172.9 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:25 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 PH
        39.33.87.181 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:30 +1100] GET /pdf/carbonate-reservoirs.html HTTP/1.1 PK
        39.33.87.181 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:31 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 PK
        39.33.87.181 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:31 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 PK
        39.33.87.181 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:31 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 PK
        66.249.92.159 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:33 +1100] GET /pdf/carbonate-reservoirs.html HTTP/1.1 US
        134.35.90.43 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:35 +1100] GET //The-Egyptian-Pyramids--Mt--Lebanon-School-District--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        134.35.90.43 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:36 +1100] GET /The-Egyptian-Pyramids--Mt--Lebanon-School-District--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        134.35.90.43 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:36 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/style.css HTTP/1.1 US
        134.35.90.43 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:36 +1100] GET /logo.jpg HTTP/1.1 US
        134.35.90.43 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:37 +1100] GET /dmcaemail.png HTTP/1.1 US
        77.88.47.68 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:38 +1100] GET /pdf/istishna.html HTTP/1.1 US
        40.77.167.138 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:38 +1100] GET /pdf/digital-newbie.html HTTP/1.1 US
        134.35.90.43 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:39 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 US
        89.3.118.149 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:42 +1100] GET //Recombinant-DNA--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 FR
        89.3.118.149 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:43 +1100] GET /Recombinant-DNA--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 FR
        89.3.118.149 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:44 +1100] GET /download.jpg HTTP/1.1 FR
        66.249.92.158 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:44 +1100] GET /Recombinant-DNA--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        54.226.130.166 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:45 +1100] GET /Recombinant-DNA--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        39.33.87.181 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:45 +1100] GET //carbonate-reservoirs-carbonet-Seismic-is-but-one-part--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 PK
        39.33.87.181 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:46 +1100] GET /carbonate-reservoirs-carbonet-Seismic-is-but-one-part--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 PK
        39.33.87.181 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:46 +1100] GET /download.jpg HTTP/1.1 PK
        66.249.92.158 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:47 +1100] GET /carbonate-reservoirs-carbonet-Seismic-is-but-one-part--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        157.55.39.228 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:47 +1100] GET /Classification-of-EEG-signals--pdf.html HTTP/1.1 US
        119.95.172.9 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:49 +1100] GET /pdf/first-vita-plus.html HTTP/1.1 PH
        39.33.87.181 - [26/Nov/2017:02:29:56 +1100] GET /wp-content/themes/vivekweb/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 PK
```

Comment: you have written *count how many times these ip addresses visited same day* - but that count is not figuring in your output. Update your expected output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I updated expected output. I didn't count how many same ip address I have. I guess it will be around 5-10

Comment: @danone Are you looking for something like `awk '{a[$NF]++ ;} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' logfile` ?

Comment: so, what is `7` in the output line `223.223.129.225-IN:7`? The `IN` code count OR the count of IP address `223.223.129.225` occurrences regarding to specific country code?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest 7 is count of ip address I looked at and count again this is the result 223.223.129.225-IN:4 168.235.194.192-US:10 correct count –

Comment: @danone, one more thing: I got 2 IP addresses with same count: `117.211.126.164-IN:4` and `223.223.129.225-IN:4`, how should they be treated?

Comment: I just want 20 ip addresses doesn't matter which one should come first, or if they are 19 just take one. I am more focus first 10 record. if 2 ip address you stated in first 20 they should be both in first 20 records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extended GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ 
         curr_d=strftime("%d/%b/%Y", systime());
         PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc" 
     }
     $3~"^\\["curr_d{ a[$8][$1]++ } 
     END{ 
         for (cc in a) { 
             for (ip in a[cc]) { 
                 print ip"-"cc":"a[cc][ip]; break 
             }
             if (++c==20) break 
         } 
     }' /var/log/mywebsite.log > /home/mywebsite/www/countries2.txt
```

---

For your additional condition *"I would like to sort count of ip address last digits which is after country prefix e.g IN:20 "*:

remove the line `if (++c==20) break` and add `| sort -t: -k2nr | head -n20` to the end of the command.

Comment: when I run this script it gives me all ip addresses listed in log files however what I would like this script does is to sort as count big to small count of ip address and only pull first 20 records If you look at example I sorted 196.249.65.222-TZ:20
157.39.204.147-ID:18
77.75.76.160-CZ:16
87.98.227.4-ES:11
196.190.64.15-ET:10
197.149.221.194-GN:5
66.249.93.84-EU:4
46.8.37.254-GR:4
212.25.107.145-IL:4
197.248.60.227-KE:4
14.139.191.225-IN:3
96.9.67.84-KH:3
105.158.149.195-MA:2
37.238.135.28-IQ:2
188.0.249.246-MD:2
188.210.148.140-IR:2
196.27.120.7-ZW:2
217.73.208.143-IT:1

Comment: @danone, use my update

Comment: it is giving me 20 record yes but is not sorted from highest to lowest record I want to sort first highest 20 ip address record then cut first 20 did you noticed how its been sorted ? 
e.g   91.151.138.133-GE:18
196.249.65.222-TZ:16
157.39.204.147-ID:14
77.75.76.160-CZ:10
87.98.227.4-ES:8
196.190.64.15-ET:5
197.149.221.194-GN:4
66.249.93.84-EU:4
46.8.37.254-GR:4
212.25.107.145-IL:3
197.248.60.227-KE:3
14.139.191.225-IN:3
96.9.67.84-KH:3
105.158.149.195-MA:2
37.238.135.28-IQ:2
188.0.249.246-MD:2
188.210.148.140-IR:2
196.27.120.7-ZW:2
217.73.208.143-IT:2
116.44.86.58-KR:2

Comment: @danone, your current input is not representative to reflect your requirements. It works fine, tested on input fragment from the question (though that input does not even contain the current day)

Comment: I sorted expected output please check again. I would like to sort count of ip address last digits which is after country prefix e.g IN:20 how can I do that ? I want only biggest 20 numbers IP-Country:19 IP-Country:17 IP-Country:15 IP-Country:13 IP-Country:10 IP-Country:8 IP-Country:8 IP-Country:5 IP-Country:5 etc. – danone 6 mins ago

Comment: @danone, so remove the line `if (++c==20) break` and add `| sort -t: -k2nr | head -n20` to the end of the command. That's all.

Comment: this is working perfectly. thank you @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=`date +%d/%b/%Y -d "1 days ago"`
awk -v i="$i" '$3~i {print $1,$NF}' /tmp/l.txt  >/tmp/ToTAL_VISITED_SITES
awk -v i="$i" '$3~i {print $1}' /tmp/l.txt| sort | uniq >/tmp/Sorted_Ips.txt
while read line1; do grep $line1 ToTAL_VISITED_SITES | uniq -c;done <Sorted_Ips.txt
```

---

/tmp/l.txt contains the input file.
From above script provide individual sites visited count today.
If you need top 20 sites Use below command:

```
sh scriptname | sort -nr| head -20
```

It worked fine for me.

Comment: I’ve downvoted your answer because you’ve continued to put prose in the code box. Please review the formatting options and corrections that I and others have made to your previous posts in order to make them more readable. Let me know if/when you have corrected this post and would be happy to undo or reverse my vote.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Please suggest to me to how to post in correct format. i am unable to do

Comment: Look at your [previous answers!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/259343/praveen-kumar-bs?tab=answers&sort=newest)